# Is a VM with 10 GB hardrive, 8 CPU's, and 4GB of RAM plausible?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I received an assignment to install Fedora 24-1.2 in VirtualBox with these specifications, and I'm running into issues that make me question how realistic this is.

For one, I'm not even able to create 8 CPUs. VirtualBox doesn't even give me the option. The most I can do is 4.

Secondly, It won't allow me to create so much RAM with only a 10gb hard drive.

I've double checked the assignment about a dozen times now and yes, that is my my instructor wants. I'll figure it out if need be... I just want to confirm, are these settings plausible?

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using? I was able to create such a VM just fine in VirtualBox 5.0.40, although it did notify me that using more than 6 CPUs (my computer has a 6-core CPU) is likely to degrade performance. In fact, the new VM wizard asks first for RAM, *then* hard disk...

Comment: How much RAM and how many cores does your host machine have?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

10GB HD, 8 CPUs, 4GB of RAM - Those settings could well be plausible for a Linux VM, I have had VMs smaller than that, and far larger too (in server grade hardware).

The needed resources depend wildly on what the server is supposed to do, however the requested resources are not probably plausible for the (host) machine/computer you are using.

You are sharing/"stealing" resources that the host is not using to give to the VM; you cannot steal what is not there; for to give virtual CPUs, disk space and RAM to a VM in Virtualbox, you have got to have the physical (free) resources to match in the (host) computer you are using.

If you have only 4GB or even 8GB of physical RAM, the OS also needs a good chunk to work properly, and won't allow you to use your full RAM for VirtualBox; the same comment applies roughly to your CPUs.

What I advise is creating a VM constrained to your hardware limits, and explaining in a report *why* you were not able/why it does not make sense  creating the resources as asked. It will probably get you some brownie points showing you understood the challenge and still managed to create the VM.

Comment: Follow it up with a purchase request (with detailed spec, and maybe some quotes from a few approved suppliers) for a server capable of running an 8-core VM with 4GB RAM and 10GB disk.  Hint: the server will need to have more than 8 CPU cores, more than 4GB RAM, and more than 10GB of disk storage available - at least enough of each to run the host OS plus anything else it might need to run (possibly including other VMs).

Comment: Doesn't a quad-core Intel CPU have 8 virtual cores due to hyperthreading?

Comment: @jamesqf Even if, you will always need at least one CPU for the host OS, I prefer leaving two cores for the host. If the host is underperforming, the hypervisor/VMs be slow too.

Comment: @jamesqf: if it's not a desktop i5, then yes it will have hyperthreading unless it's ancient (like Core2Quad).  I think all Xeons with Sandybridge-family microarchitectures have hyperthreading.  (i.e. Sandybridge Exxxx through Skylake to Exxxx v6).  Depending on the workload, the hypervisor may not need much CPU time to itself, but I haven't looked at VM provisioning benchmarks.  If running the VM under a host OS instead of Xen-style with hypervisor on the bare metal, then you could still run a VM with as many virtual CPUs as you have, if you strip down the host OS so it's doing ~nothing.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro in VirtualBox it’s perfectly possible to assign all existing CPU threads to VM. They will just be shared with host OS.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's going to depend on the workload. If the workload running inside the VM is CPU intensive and you aren't running anything else CPU intensive on the host you should be getting the best performance by making the number of virtual CPUs match the number of physical CPUs. But if you are running anything else CPU intensive on the host you will likely get better performance with a lower number of virtual CPUs. I cannot imagine any workload where more virtual CPUs than physical CPUs would be a good idea.

Comment: @PeterCordes The hypervisor does not indeed needs much load. The OS might need a little more, in the case discussed here of Virtualbox. Xeon is a whole different game though.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev I prefer not to share  if I can choose. But I do agree you will use better the hw. Professionally, I only used VMware ESX and Xen.

Comment: If you are assigning near 100% of the resources of the host, it begs the question as to why one is virtualizing.

Comment: @mkingsbu The scope of this question is different from real world experience. But yeah, getting to the point, I agree 100%. I know however people who choose to install a well known ERP and Oracle under VMWare, despite being advised to install in bare metal just because they felt on more control of that. Oddities.

Comment: Oh, I just reread and it looks like homework or something.  Weird assignment. I would have thought installing it to be sufficient.

Comment: @kasperd: For a real workload, I think I agree, but there have been times when I want to test code running on more CPUs than I actually have handy.